# Which HTML tags can have a title attribute?

Tags: html, tags, attributes, title

I know `<th>`, `<a>`, `<p>`, `<h1>`…`<h5>` can all use title attributes. Which other tags can use them?

I'm currently optimising a website for SEO purposes by adding title attributes with keywords associated with the website

Comment: Don't try to optimise for SEO by keyword stuffing title attributes. It will probably turn out to be counter productive. Design for your readers, trust search engines to handle that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title attribute works with all HTML tags. It's a global attribute. You can see the list of all HTML tags [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/).

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_standardattributes.asp

Answer (score 0):

The [title attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-title-attribute) can be found in the [global attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#global-attributes) section of the [HTML 5 recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) which says:

> The following attributes are common to and may be specified on all HTML elements (even those not defined in this specification)